# SQL - Total Pivot Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

for the following sql script, I would like to add a "Total" column at the end to sum the data in the columns for each row.

please help:

```
select * from 
(SELECT       Calender.YrPer, [Period DATA 6b].PRODUCT_NO, isnull(sum([Period DATA 6b].LI_QTY+[Period DATA 6b].RG_QTY*1.0),0) as "TotalUnits"
FROM            Calender INNER JOIN
                         [Period DATA 6b] ON Calender.[Starting Period] = [Period DATA 6b].STARTING_PERIOD LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Allproducts ON [Period DATA 6b].PRODUCT_NO = Allproducts.PRODUCT_NO
where Calender.YrPer >= '2012P05'
group by Calender.YrPer, [Period DATA 6b].PRODUCT_NO)

as test1
pivot
(
sum(TotalUnits)
for YrPer
in ([2012P05],[2012P06],[2012P07],[2012P08],[2012P09],[2012P10],[2012P11],[2012P12],[2012P13],[2013P01],[2013P02],[2013P03],[2013P04],[2013P05],[2013P06],[2013P07],[2013P08],[2013P09],[2013P10],[2013P11],[2013P12],[2013P13],[2014P01],[2014P02],[2014P03],[2014P04])
)
PivotTable
order by PRODUCT_NO
```

Sample Desired output:

```
PRODUCT_NO  2012P05 2012P06 2012P07 2012P08 2012P09 2012P10 2012P11 2012P12 2012P13     2013P01 2013P02 2013P03 2013P04 2013P05 2013P06 2013P07 2013P08 2013P09 2013P10 2013P11     2013P12 2013P13 2014P01 2014P02 2014P03 2014P04 2013 R52    2014 R52
75  551 506 473 261 557 1037    285 250 278 234 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        4432    0
174 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   0
216 NULL    NULL    0   0   0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    0   0
```

Comment: Is this a report?  It may be easier for you to use whatever you are using to deliver this report (SSRS?) to include a sum column

Comment: This is sql server 2014. I am just using sql to create a pivot table report but need the total column using sql.

Comment: @Ben You may be able to use `sum() over()` in your subquery where you partition the data, but it would be much easier to help if you added a small set of sample data with your tables. [Similar to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322488/transpose-pivot-rows-to-columns-and-sum/18322557#18322557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code, add union plus query to get total group by only PRODUCT_NO. The YrPer set to constant "TotalPerProduct" and use this constant in the pivot.
Since you did not include any sample data. I just added the code and I think it should work.

try ..

```
    select * from 
(SELECT       Calender.YrPer, [Period DATA 6b].PRODUCT_NO, isnull(sum([Period DATA 6b].LI_QTY+[Period DATA 6b].RG_QTY*1.0),0) as "TotalUnits"
FROM            Calender INNER JOIN
                         [Period DATA 6b] ON Calender.[Starting Period] = [Period DATA 6b].STARTING_PERIOD LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Allproducts ON [Period DATA 6b].PRODUCT_NO = Allproducts.PRODUCT_NO
where Calender.YrPer >= '2012P05'
group by Calender.YrPer, [Period DATA 6b].PRODUCT_NO
UNION
SELECT       'TotalPerProduct' YrPer, [Period DATA 6b].PRODUCT_NO, isnull(sum([Period DATA 6b].LI_QTY+[Period DATA 6b].RG_QTY*1.0),0) as "TotalUnits"
FROM            Calender INNER JOIN
                         [Period DATA 6b] ON Calender.[Starting Period] = [Period DATA 6b].STARTING_PERIOD LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Allproducts ON [Period DATA 6b].PRODUCT_NO = Allproducts.PRODUCT_NO
where Calender.YrPer >= '2012P05'
group by [Period DATA 6b].PRODUCT_NO

)

as test1
pivot
(
sum(TotalUnits)
for YrPer
in ([2012P05],[2012P06],[2012P07],[2012P08],[2012P09],[2012P10],[2012P11],[2012P12],[2012P13],[2013P01],[2013P02],[2013P03],[2013P04],[2013P05],[2013P06],[2013P07],[2013P08],[2013P09],[2013P10],[2013P11],[2013P12],[2013P13],[2014P01],[2014P02],[2014P03],[2014P04], [TotalPerProduct])
)
PivotTable
order by PRODUCT_NO
```

Comment: Thank you t_m , it works. I am assuming, this would be the easiest/efficient way to calculate total?

Comment: I am sorry that i cant vote since I dont have 15 + rep.

Comment: I believe so unless someone out there comments with a better way.