# How can I transpose SQL Server rows to multiple column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I transpose a SQL Server row of data to multiple columns? I have data something like show below

```
     [STOCK NO]        [PN1]           [PN2]             [PN3]         [PN4]                          [PN4]          [PN5]         [PN6]       [PN7]       [PN8]                    [PN9]   [PN10]  [PN11]   [PN12]    [Qty] 
    700349L           600446            201743           100208                                      300219          400533                  100280        100218                   100222          100220    100221      1
```

I would like to see something like this

```
[STOCK NO]        [bomRev]      [bomEntry]  [partId] [qty]  [cmnt]  [srcLoc]    [dType]    [lead]   [lineNbr]
700349L             A               1         600446  1      `TEST`   TEST       0           0       1
700349L             A               2         201743  1      `TEST`   TEST       0           0       2
700349L             A               3         100208  1      `TEST`   TEST       0           0       3
700349L             A               4         300219  1      `TEST`   TEST       0           0       4

700349L             A               5         400533  1       `TEST`   TEST       0           0       5

700349L             A               6         100218  1       `TEST`   TEST       0           0       6
700349L             A               7         100222  1       `TEST`   TEST       0           0       7
700349L             A               8         100220  1       `TEST`   TEST       0           0       8
700349L             A               9         100221  1       `TEST`   TEST       0           0       9
```

Then I want to use insert from select statement as shown below but I like to transpose the row to multiple columns

```
 INSERT INTO [DT]([bomItem], [bomRev], [bomEntry], [partId], [qty], [cmnt],[srcLoc], [dType], [lead], [lineNbr])
     SELECT 
         [STOCK NO], 'A', [bomEntry], [partid], [qty], 'TEST', 'TEST', '0', '0', [lineNbr]
     FROM 
         [ST]
```

[image: skip if blank]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose/Pivot Rows to Columns and Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322488/transpose-pivot-rows-to-columns-and-sum) and [SQL Total - Pivot Column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25293671/62576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses the columns and example data prior to additional edits in the question.

using `cross apply()` to unpivot your columns and `row_number()` to number only those rows that have a value:

```
--INSERT INTO [DT]([bomItem], [bomRev], [bomEntry], [partId], [qty], [cmnt],[srcLoc], [dType], [lead], [lineNbr])
select 
    st.[CALC STOCK NO]    
  , bomRev = 'A'
  , bomEntry = row_number() over (order by u.ordinal)
  , u.Partid
  , st.Qty
  , cmnt = 'Test'
  , srcLoc = 'Test'
  , dType = '0'
  , lead = '0'
  , lineNbr = row_number() over (order by u.ordinal)
from st
  cross apply (values 
     (1,[BOM WHEEL PN])
    ,(2,[BOM TIRE PN])
    ,(3,[BOM VALVE PN])
    ,(4,[BOM - SECONDARY DISC PN])
    ,(5,[BOM - DISC])
    ,(6,[BOM - RIM])
    ,(7,[BUY WHEEL])
    ,(8,[COLOR PN])
    ,(9,[WHL BOM PART 1 PN])
    ,(10,[WHL BOM PART 2 PN])
    ,(11,[WHL BOM PART 3 PN])
    ,(12,[WHL BOM PART 4 PN])
    ,(13,[WHL BOM PART 5 PN])
) u (ordinal, partId)
where nullif(u.partId,'') is not null
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XNGB57562

returns:

```
+---------------+--------+----------+--------+-----+------+--------+-------+------+---------+
| CALC STOCK NO | bomRev | bomEntry | Partid | Qty | cmnt | srcLoc | dType | lead | lineNbr |
+---------------+--------+----------+--------+-----+------+--------+-------+------+---------+
| 700349L       | A      |        1 | 600446 |   1 | Test | Test   |     0 |    0 |       1 |
| 700349L       | A      |        2 | 201743 |   1 | Test | Test   |     0 |    0 |       2 |
| 700349L       | A      |        3 | 100208 |   1 | Test | Test   |     0 |    0 |       3 |
| 700349L       | A      |        4 | 300219 |   1 | Test | Test   |     0 |    0 |       4 |
| 700349L       | A      |        5 | 400533 |   1 | Test | Test   |     0 |    0 |       5 |
| 700349L       | A      |        6 | 100280 |   1 | Test | Test   |     0 |    0 |       6 |
| 700349L       | A      |        7 | 100218 |   1 | Test | Test   |     0 |    0 |       7 |
| 700349L       | A      |        8 | 100222 |   1 | Test | Test   |     0 |    0 |       8 |
| 700349L       | A      |        9 | 100220 |   1 | Test | Test   |     0 |    0 |       9 |
| 700349L       | A      |       10 | 100221 |   1 | Test | Test   |     0 |    0 |      10 |
+---------------+--------+----------+--------+-----+------+--------+-------+------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! two things 1. can i use inserted table to create trigger? 2. how can i ignore/skip if  blank Part i added image to show

Comment: @user8066749 Updated my answer to remove the empty strings from results with `nullif(u.partId,'') is not null` instead of just `u.partid is not null`. I also included a commented out `insert` statement before the query that you can use to insert into the table you are describing.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pivot should work for you.
Check out this link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx
If you post enough dummy data someone would be able to help you along with the query. You can utilize something like http://rextester.com/ to share dummy data.
Good Luck!